# Prove that fractional Brownian motion is not a semimartingale using the p-variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

> What follows, up to the horizontal line, is taken from [Rogers "Arbitrage with fractional Brownian motion"](http://www.long-memory.com/fractional-brownian-motion/Rogers1997.pdf).

Consider an interval $[0,T]$ on which is defined the fractional Brownian motion $B$, and consider its partitions $\pi_n = \{t^n_k = \frac{kT}{n} : 0\le k\le n\},\ n\in\mathbb N$.

Let $p\ge1$, the $p$-variation of $B$ is
$$
    V_p(B) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |B(t^n_{k+1})-B(t^n_k)|^p = 
    \begin{cases}
        \infty, & \text{if }\ pH < 1, \\
        0,       & \text{if }\ pH > 1.
    \end{cases}
$$
If $H>1/2$ we can choose $p\in(1,\frac1H)$ so that $pH<1$, then the $p$-variation is infinite, hence the quadratic variation of $B$ is infinite too.

If $H<1/2$ we can choose $p>2$ so that $pH<1$, then again we obtain that the $p$-variation and the quadratic variation of $B$ are infinite.

In both cases the quadratic variation of $B$ is not finite, hence the fBm is not a semimartingale for $H\ne1/2$.

---

Could somebody further explain the above reasoning? I don't fully get what has to be proved, is it related to the fact that a semimartingale has to have finite *variation*? But which *variation*: quadratic, p-variation or another one?

Moreover, I don't understand how to deduce what the quadratic variation is, given that we know the p-variation. Is it related to the fact that given $p_1<p_2$ then $V_{p_2}\le V_{p_1}$?

Fianlly, what about the case $H=1/2$, in which $B$ is the usual Brownian motion? If we take $p\in(1,2)$ then we are still in the case $pH<1$ and so the $p$-variation is infinite hence the quadratic variation of $B$ is infinite too, contradicting the fact that B is a martingale.

Comment: I think you've misstated Rogers' argument for $H > 1/2$.  Read page 98 of the paper again.

Comment: The key is that a semimartingale always has finite quadratic variation, and if its quadratic variation is zero, then it is of bounded (1-)variation.

Comment: It is true that if $p_1 < p_2$ then $V_{p_2} \le V_{p_1}$.  More is true: if $V_{p_1} < \infty$ then $V_{p_2} = 0$.

Comment: And in the $H=1/2$ case, it is absolutely true that Brownian motion has infinite $p$-variation for every $p < 2$, but that does not imply its quadratic variation is infinite, and indeed it is not.

Comment: @NateEldredge Oh ok I got it thank you very much!

Comment: @NateEldredge Even stronger, Brownian motion has infinite $p$-variation for every $p\leq 2$. The $2$ variation of Brownian motion is infinite a.s.

Comment: @user341290: You mean in the sense where we take the supremum over partitions, instead of the limit in probability as mesh goes to zero?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes. Small point, but it is good to clarify in questions like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $B$ is a semimartingale, then it has finite quadratic variation.

Recall that if $s < b$ then $V_b \le V_s$.

- If $H<1/2$ we can choose $p>2$ s.t. $pH<1 \implies V_p = \infty \implies \infty\le V_2 \implies V_2 = \infty$, i.e. the quadratic variation ($p=2$) is infinite too: contradiction.
- If $H>1/2$ we can choose $p\in(\frac1H,2)$ s.t. $pH>1 \implies V_p = 0 \implies V_2 \le 0 \implies V_2 = 0 \implies B$ must have finite variation. But on the other hand, for $p\in(1,\frac1H)$ we have $V_p = \infty$, hence $B$ cannot have finite variation: contradiction.

Either way, if $H\ne\frac12$, the fBm is not a semimartingale.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B^{H}_{\cdot}$ denote the fBM with Hurst parameter $H\in (0,1)$.  This is a centered Gaussian process with [Covariance function](http://www.math.univ-brest.fr/perso/rainer.buckdahn/March%202010/presentation/School/LEON/introduccion.pdf#page=11) (i.e.: $\Sigma(t,s) =\mathbb{E}[B_t^HB_s^H] $):
$$
\Sigma(t,s)= 2^{-1}\left(
t^{2H} - s^{2H} - |t-s|^{2H}
\right)\qquad \boldsymbol{(1)}.
$$
We may therefore apply [this Komologorov-Chestov argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309173/gaussian-process-h%C3%B6lder-continous-paths) (i.e.: [Theorem 1 in these lecture notes](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Elalley/Courses/385/Old/GaussianProcesses.pdf)) to (1) deduce that $B_{\cdot}^H$ has a version with $H$-[Hölder-continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) paths.  Therefore, it [must have a version with finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-variation#Link_with_H%C3%B6lder_norm) $H^{-1}$-variation.

Since we know that every semi-martingale [has finite quadratic variation](https://planetmath.org/quadraticvariationofasemimartingale) then if $H\neq 2^{-1}$ $B_{\cdot}^H$ is not a semi-martingale.

**Note:**  This doesn't show that it is a (semi-)martingale for $H=2^{-1}$.