# Fractional Brownian motion of Riemann-Liouville type is not a semimartingale

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, brownian-motion

Given a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{F},\mathbb{P})$ satisfying the usual conditions, $B$ a standard one-dimensional Brownian motion and $H\in(0,1/2)$. Consider the process $X$ given by
$$
X_t = \int_0^t \frac{(t-s)^{H-1/2}}{\Gamma(H+1/2)} d B_s,
$$
where $\Gamma$ denotes the gamma function.
The process $X$ is called fractional Brownian motion of Riemann-Liouville type with Hurst parameter $H.$ I have read in various articles that it is well-known that $X$ is not a semimartingale. I am trying to understand why this statement is true. However, I find it difficult to show this. I tried approximating the non-differentiable kernel $K(t)=\frac{t^{H-1/2}}{\Gamma(H+1/2)}$ by continuously differentiable kernels, $\varepsilon>0,$
$$
K_\varepsilon(t)= \frac{(t+\varepsilon)^{H-1/2}}{\Gamma(H+1/2)}.
$$
Then, an application of the stochastic Fubini theorem shows that
$$
X_t^\varepsilon = \int_0^t K_\varepsilon(t-s) dB_s
$$
is a semimartingale with quadratic variation $ \langle X^\varepsilon\rangle_t = K_\varepsilon(0)^2 t $ and $\langle X^\varepsilon\rangle_t\to\infty$ as $\varepsilon\downarrow0.$ Moreover, I was able to show that $\mathbb{E}(|X_t^\varepsilon-X_t|^2)\to0$ as $\varepsilon\downarrow0.$ Now, I aim to conclude that $\langle X\rangle_t=\infty$ which would yield the claim.

I would be grateful for any suggestion on how to finish my proof or any other way that shows the assertion.

Answer (score 3):

It is well known that the fractional Brownian motion is not a semi martingale unless H=1/2; see for instance this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354808/prove-that-fractional-brownian-motion-is-not-a-semimartingale-using-the-p-variat) or Section 2 in this [paper](http://www.long-memory.com/fractional-brownian-motion/Rogers1997.pdf). Then, from Proposition 9 in the paper [Equivalence of Volterra processes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414903000887)  the Riemann-Liouville process is locally equivalent to the fractional Brownian motion. Therefore the Riemann-Liouville process is not a semi martingale unless H=1/2.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and drawing my attention to this interesting paper about the equivalence of Volterra processes! I have to think about your "therefore". In particular, is it clear that two continuous processes that are locally equivalent are neither both a semimartingale nor both not a semimartingale?

Comment: The "therefore" follows from Girsanov theorem, but essentially if P(<X>_T <+\infty)=0 for one process then it should also be zero for the other process since the laws of the two processes are equivalent on the time interval [0,T]

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}\newcommand{\be}{\beta}\newcommand\ip[1]{\langle #1\rangle}\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$This property is briefly proved in Section 5.1 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/2012.00975v1). The proof is based on Basse's characterization of the spectral representation of Gaussian semimartingales, namely, [Theorem 4.6](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10959-009-0246-2).

---

Here are details on this. It follows from Basse's theorem that, if $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ were a semimartingale, then we would have
\begin{equation*}
    (t-s)^\al=g(s)+\int_s^t\Psi_r(s)\mu(dr) \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
for all real $t\ge0$ and almost all (a.a.) $s\in[0,t]$, where $\al:=H-1/2\in(-1/2,0)$, $g\colon\R_+\to\R$ is square integrable on $[0,t]$ for all real $t\ge0$, $\mu$ is a Radon measure
on $\R_+$, and $\R_+\times\R_+\ni(t,s)\mapsto\Psi_t(s)\in\R$ is a measurable mapping such that $\|\Psi_r\|_{L^2(\R_+)}=1$.

In view of the Tonelli theorem, it follows from \eqref{1} that for a.a. triples $(s,c,t)$ such that $0<s<c<t<\infty$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    \int_c^t\al(r-s)^{\al-1}\,dr=\int_c^t\Psi_r(s)\mu(dr).  \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
Since $\al(r-s)^{\al-1}<0$ for $r\in(c,t)$, we see that the Lebesgue measure on $(0,\infty)$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mu$, with some density $h$, so that $h(r)=\frac{dr}{\mu(dr)}$ for real $r>0$. So, \eqref{2} implies
\begin{equation*}
    \int_c^t\al(r-s)^{\al-1}\,h(r)\mu(dr)=\int_c^t\Psi_r(s)\mu(dr)  
\end{equation*}
for a.a. triples $(s,c,t)$ such that $0<s<c<t<\infty$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    \Psi_r(s)=\al(r-s)^{\al-1}\,h(r)  \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}
for $\mu$-a.a. pairs $(s,r)$ such that $0<s<r<\infty$. Since the Lebesgue measure on $(0,\infty)$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mu$, we get \eqref{3} for a.a. pairs $(s,r)$ such that $0<s<r<\infty$.

For any real $r>0$ with $h(r)\ne0$, by \eqref{3},
\begin{equation*}
    1=\|\Psi_r\|_{L^2(\R_+)}^2\ge\al^2 h(r)^2\int_0^r(r-s)^{2\al-2}\,ds=\infty,
\end{equation*}
a contradiction.

Finally, if $h(r)=0$ for a.a. real $r>0$, then, by \eqref{3}, $\Psi_r(s)=0$ for a.a. pairs $(s,r)$ such that $0<s<r<\infty$, which contradicts \eqref{1}. $\quad\Box$

---

**Details on \eqref{2}:** Recall that \eqref{1} holds for all real $t\ge0$ and a.a. $s\in[0,t]$. Replace each of the two entries of $t$ in \eqref{1} by $c\in(s,t)$ and refer to this modification of \eqref{1} as \eqref{1}$_c$. By the Tonelli theorem, the conjunction of \eqref{1} and \eqref{1}$_c$ holds for a.a. triples $(s,c,t)$ such that $0<s<c<t<\infty$. For any such $(s,c,t)$, subtract the left-hand side of \eqref{1}$_c$ from that of \eqref{1}, and also subtract the right-hand side of \eqref{1}$_c$ from that of \eqref{1}. Then ($g(s)$ disappears and) we get \eqref{2} for a.a. triples $(s,c,t)$ such that $0<s<c<t<\infty$.

**Further details, on the use of the Tonelli theorem, to show that the conjunction of \eqref{1} and \eqref{1}$_c$ holds for a.a. triples $(s,c,t)$ such that $0<s<c<t<\infty$:** Let $T\subset\R^3$ denote the set of triples $(s,c,t)$ such that $0<s<c<t<\infty$ and the conjunction of \eqref{1} and \eqref{1}$_c$ fails to hold. We want to show that the Lebesgue measure $|T|$ of $T$ is $0$. Let $S\subset\R^2$ denote the set of pairs $(s,t)$ such that $t\ge0$, $s\in[0,t]$, and \eqref{1} fails to hold. Then, in view of the Tonelli theorem,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    |S|&=\iint_{\R^2}ds\,dt\,1(t\ge0, s\in[0,t], \text{\eqref{1} fails to hold}) \\ 
    &=\int_\R dt\,1(t\ge0)\int_\R ds\,1(s\in[0,t], \text{\eqref{1} fails to hold}) \\ 
    &=\int_\R dt\,1(t\ge0)0=0, 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
since \eqref{1} holds for all real $t\ge0$ and a.a. $s\in[0,t]$.
Note that
\begin{equation*}
    T\subseteq\{(s,c,t)\colon(s,t)\in S\text{ or }(s,c)\in S\}. 
\end{equation*}
So, again in view of the Tonelli theorem,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    |T|&=\iiint_{\R^3}ds\,dc\,dt\,(1(s,c,t)\in T)) \\ 
    &\le\iiint_{\R^3}ds\,dc\,dt\,(1((s,t)\in S)+1((s,c)\in S)) \\ 
    &=\int_\R dc\,\iint_{\R^2}ds\,dt\,(1((s,t)\in S)
    +\int_\R dt\,\iint_{\R^2}ds\,dc\,(1((s,c)\in S) \\ 
    &=\int_\R dc\,|S|
    +\int_\R dt\,|S|=0.  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Thus, $|T|=0$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort you have put into your answer. I really appreciate it. Your reasoning is clear and I understand the idea. The only thing I do not get is how you obtained (2) from Tonelli's theorem. In particular, what did happen to $g$?

Comment: @El_mago : I have added details on this. Please let me know if further details are needed.

Comment: Many thanks again for your explanation. I do not get, how Tonelli's theorem is used? I only know it as a special case of Fubini's theorem.

Comment: @El_mago : I have added further details on the use of the Tonelli theorem. (BTW, it is not a special case of the Fubini theorem -- because, in contrast with the Fubini theorem, the Tonelli theorem holds for all nonnegative measurable functions.)

Comment: Many thanks for adding further details and pointing out my mistake.