# Convergence of the quadratic variation process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose we are given a sequence of stochastic processes $X^n, n\in\mathbb{N},$ with finite quadratic variations and a stochastic process $X$ such that for every $t\geq0$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(|X^n_t-X_t|^2) =0.
$$
Is it then possible to infer convergence of the quadratic variations, i.e. for every $t\geq0$, $\langle X^n\rangle_t\to\langle X\rangle_t$ in some sense, perhaps $L^2$?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no - I will construct processes $X^n$ on $[0, 1]$ such that the limit in question holds for $X$ the zero process, but $\limsup_n \langle X^n \rangle_t =\infty$ almost surely for every $t \in (0, 1]$.

Indeed, for $n \in \mathbb Z_+$, and $1 \leq k \leq 2^n$, let $Z_{n, k}$ be identically distributed jointly independent random variables equal to $0$ or $1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each.

Define

$$X^n = \sum_{k = 1}^{2^{n}} Z_{n, k} \, \mathbf 1_{(\frac{k-1}{2^n}, \frac{k-1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^{2n}})}.$$

That the limit in question holds is obvious, since for every $0 \leq t \leq 1$, $X_n^t$ is almost surely $0$ for all large enough $n$.

We clearly have

$$\langle X^n \rangle_t = 2 \, |\{1 \leq k \leq 2^n t \, | \, Z_{n, k} = 1\}|.$$

Since the $Z_{n, k}$ are independent of each other, $B_{n, t} := |\{1 \leq k \leq 2^n t \, | \, Z_{n, k} = 1\}|$ is binomially distributed with success rate $\frac{1}{2}$ and number of trials equal to $[2^n t]$. Thus by symmetry of the binomial distribution,

$$\mathbb P \left (\langle X^n \rangle_t \geq [2^n t] \right ) \geq \frac{1}{2}.$$

By independence of the $X^n$ from each other, the events $E_n := \{   \langle X^n \rangle_t \geq [2^n t]   \}$ are independent.

Thus by the second Borel-Cantelli lemma,
$\langle X^n \rangle_t \geq [2^n t]$ infinitely often, almost surely; and so $\limsup_n \langle X^n \rangle_t = \infty$ almost surely, as claimed.

Comment: Many thanks for your excellent counterexample. My questions were raised while I am trying to show that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(|X^n_t-X_t|^2)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle X^n\rangle=\infty$ then I hope to infer $\langle X\rangle=\infty.$ This seems to be still possible to prove. I am also additionally assuming that the $X^n$s have continuous sample paths. Do you have an idea how to prove this?

Comment: Hmm, I don’t see how immediately. Perhaps you could create a separate thread to ask the modified question, maybe others can help.

Comment: Actually, i think this is still not possible even with the assumption that it be continuous. Vaguely, the idea is to replace the jumps in this example with small continuous segments with nontrivial quadratic variation. This will yield essentially the same counterexample.

Comment: The original problem I am working on, I have already explained [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446360/fractional-brownian-motion-of-riemann-liouville-type-is-not-a-semimartingale) There I was suggested to use other methods to prove the questioned claim which I am grateful for. However, I still try to finish the idea I had.

Comment: In fact I just realised you can even take $X^n$, $X$ to be deterministic… just take any sequence $f_n$ of continuous functions with quadratic variations going to $\infty$ converging uniformly to $0$, and set $X_n = f_n, X = 0$ a.s.